# Never used LocalDB before

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, localdb

I have never used LocalDB in an application before.  I have two questions:

1) Is LocalDB used for testing only or is it sometimes rolled out to the live environment?
2) I notice that the connection string varies from PC to PC.  For example, please see the connection string below which works on my desktop PC (with Visual Studio 2013):

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbCurrency.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

and the connection string below, which works on my Tablet PC (with Visual Studio Community 2015):

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbCurrency.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Why is the data source different on each PC.  How do you know, which data source the client PC has?

3) Does the client PC have to have SQL Server Express installed for the app to work?

Comment: LocalDB is intended for development only, but you can (ab)use it by "sharing" databases or installing it on individual machines. It is not SQL Express, it is a different download. if you are looking for embedded databases, use SQLite or SqlCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, LocalDB is really used for testing. While there's nothing preventing you from using it in a production environment, it's not going to be supported.
2. The data source is different because LocalDB can still run distinct instances. You can manage these with the command line tool, for example:

   List all instances:

   ```
   SqlLocalDB info
   ```

   Create new instance:

   ```
   SqlLocalDb create MyLocalDb
   ```
3. No, LocalDB is completely separate from SQL Server Express

I recomend reading this MSDN article which has a good introduction to LocalDB: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/